# How to force my header to be on top?

Tags: css, html, header, z-index

so I have this little beginning of a site and I want the top menu to stay on top of anything else. I used position:fixed and now it does stay on top of everything except for one div that display a logo... I tried using z-index but that didn't help. How do I force that header to stay on top without using Js if possible...

The "blackBar" passes on top of the heading but it's the only this that does...

```
<body>
<div id="pageBloc">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Stuff1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stuff2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stuff3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stuff4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stuff5</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div id="topBloc">

            <div id="blackBar">
                <p id="logo"><img src="Images/logoSmall.png" alt="logo"</p>
                <h1 id="titrePrincipal">MyTitle</h1>
                <h2 id="soustitrePrincipal">SubTitle/h2>
            </div>

        </div>

        <section id="temporatySection">

        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS

```
body, html
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
}
#pageBloc
{
    height:100%;
}

/*Header*/

header
{   
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #26292E;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;

}

nav ul, nav li
{
    margin-top:5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#topBloc
{
    background: url('Images/backgroundBloc12.jpg') fixed center;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#blackBar
{
    background: rgba(38,41,46,0.80);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo 
{
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center; 
}

#titrePrincipal
{
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
}

#soustitrePrincipal
{
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}

#temporarySection
{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Given your current coding - http://jsfiddle.net/gGMzD/ - looks fine to me..

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative; z-index: -1;` to `#logo`.

Then, make sure that you add `z-index: -2` to `#blackbar`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/gGMzD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of position fixed, you can try

```
position: absolute
top: 0
left: 0
right: 0
z-index: 100
```

but if you must use position fixed, you can disregard this and see the answer above.